# Assign UserControl declared variable, into another UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, user-controls

Tried to find some references to similar questions, but none of them leaded me for solving my problem.
I have a UserControl - ProjectWizardProgressBar, in which I declare and use a variable. It looks like this:

```
namespace Todiste.Views.Proyectos.ProjectWizardProgressBar
public partial class ProjectWizardProgressBar : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
private string _test;
    public string test
    {
        get { return _test; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _test)
            {
                _test = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("test");
            }
        }
    }
public ProjectWizardProgressBar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;            
        test = "This is a test dummy";
    }
...
}
```

This User control I am using in a different UserControl - NewProjectStep1View, in which I have to re-assign the variable test. In a way like this:

```
namespace Todiste.Views.Proyectos.NewProjectWizard
{

public partial class NewProjectStep1View : UserControl, INewProjectWizardStep
{
public void OnStepLoaded()
    {
        ProjectWizardProgressBar.ProjectWizardProgressBar.test = "This is an updated test text" ;            

    }
...
}
```

At this moment, when I am re-assigning the variable like this, I get: 
 "An object reference is requiered for the non-static field, method, or property 'ProjectWizardProgressBar.test'".

Will be really appreciated for helping me to understand this type of data binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer for question will be:
On the necessary controller (NewProjectStep1View) create a new child instance of original UserController (ProjectWizardProgressBar) with updated value of variable.
Code below:

```
namespace Todiste.Views.Proyectos.NewProjectWizard
{

public partial class NewProjectStep1View : UserControl, INewProjectWizardStep
{
public void OnStepLoaded()
{
    ProjectWizardProgressBar progressBar = new ProjectWizardProgressBar();
    progressBar.test = "This is an updated test text";    

}
...
}
```

Hope it would be helpful.